# Possible to change the height inside the highchart drilldown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I tried to create the dynamic height in high chart's drill down. Depends on data. Then chart type is `bar chart`. 
For example

```
drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ], $("#container").css({'height':'500px'}) // here i want to change
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ], $("#container").css({'height':'300px'}) // here i want to change
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ], $("#container").css({'height':'400px'}) // here i want to change
        }]
    }
```

It is possible to add the jQuery into series section. I mentioned above. Or else any possible way for to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can catch [drilldown event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) and then call [setSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize) function.

Answer (score 3):

```
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        events: {drilldown:function(a){ this.setSize(300, a.seriesOptions.data.length*100) }}
    }
```

drilldown function is trigger as an when user is click on individual bar and argument "a" is holding the series data of that particular bar which user has click, and I've calculate the length of that data with "a.seriesOptions.data.length*100" and 100 is 100px, so if length is 2 then 2*100px = 200px.

Comment: drilldown function is trigger as an when user is click on individual bar and argument "a" is holding the series data of that particular bar which user has click, and I've calculate the length of that data with "a.seriesOptions.data.length*100" and 100 is 100px, so if length is 2 then 2*100px = 200px.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please edit your answer and post this comment in it?